# Change value of data-val=true dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, unobtrusive-validation

I have multiple tabs in which un-obstrusive validations are used, tabs are show and hide on dropdown value, Problem is when i false the data-val value of div tabs which are hide, they can not be true again, help me for change true and false of data-val value dynamically, here is my script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var myItem = $('#@Html.IdFor(m => m.INDUSTRY_ID)');
        if (myItem.val() == '41') {
            debugger;
                $("#tab_1_1 [data-val]").attr("data-val", true);
                $("#tab_1_5 [data-val]").attr("data-val", true);
                $("#tab_1_6 [data-val]").attr("data-val", true);
                $("#tab_1_2 [data-val]").attr("data-val", false);
               $("#tab_1_7 [data-val]").attr("data-val", false);

                $("#ind").show();
                $("#ind1").show();
                $("#ind2").show();
                document.getElementById("ind").click();
                //$("#business").data("validator").settings.ignore = "";
                $("#business").hide();     
                $("#business1").hide();

            }
            else {
                $("#tab_1_2 [data-val]").attr("data-val", true);
                $("#tab_1_7 [data-val]").attr("data-val", true);
                $("#tab_1_1 [data-val]").attr("data-val", false);
                $("#tab_1_5 [data-val]").attr("data-val", false);
                $("#tab_1_6 [data-val]").attr("data-val", false);


                $("#business").show();
                $("#business1").show();
                document.getElementById("business").click();
                $("#ind").hide();   
                $("#ind1").hide();           
                $("#ind2").hide();

            }

    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#INDUSTRY_ID').on('change', function () {
            if (this.value == '41') {
                debugger;
                $('form').removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
                $('form').removeData('validator');
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('form');


                $("#tab_1_1 [data-val]").attr("data-val", true);
                $("#tab_1_5 [data-val]").attr("data-val", true);
                $("#tab_1_6 [data-val]").attr("data-val", true);

                $("#tab_1_2 [data-val]").attr("data-val", false);
                $("#tab_1_7 [data-val]").attr("data-val", false);

                $("#ind").show();
                $("#ind1").show();
                $("#ind2").show();
                document.getElementById("ind").click();
                $("#business").hide();
                $("#business1").hide();

            }
            else {
                $("#tab_1_2 [data-val]").attr("data-val", true);
                $("#tab_1_7 [data-val]").attr("data-val", true);
                $("#tab_1_1 [data-val]").attr("data-val", false);
                $("#tab_1_5 [data-val]").attr("data-val", false);
                $("#tab_1_6 [data-val]").attr("data-val", false);
                $("#business").show();
                $("#business1").show();          
                document.getElementById("business").click();
                $("#ind").hide();
                $("#ind1").hide();
                $("#ind2").hide();

            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: I think you need `.data('val', true/false)`

Comment: @Satpal - `.data()` method is a jQuery method that only updates cache. Actual attribute change will not be reflected in DOM, but `.attr()` will actually change the DOM

Comment: @Awol I am very well aware of that since OP is using un-obstrusive validations, I am not sure what the library uses thus posted a comment not an answer.

Comment: @Satpal - `"help me for change true and false of data-val value dynamically"` - I assume he wants to change the attributes

Comment: with .data('val', true/false), validations ask on hide tabs. i wanted validations on show tabs either active or onactive

Comment: @Awol, OP is already using `.attr()` then it should work

Comment: i want to true again of data-val value which is false on page load because tabs are hide